# Basic likelihood ratio test

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio

I should perform a likelihood ratio test on the following null hypothesis :
α = Aψ

where α  and A (p * m)  are known vectors. ψ (m*r) is a matrix of free parameters.
The likelihood ratio test is asymptotically distributed as χ2  with r(p-m) degrees of freedom.

**What I don't understand is that normally, LR tests compare 2 models. But here it's not the case?**

I tried this on R but not sure of it since I didn't include the ψ matrix, that confuses me.

```
A=c(1,0)
testo1<-G$othog.alpha ~A
lrtest(testo1)
```

`G$othog.alpha` is my vector of α (2 values).

Comment: Is this a self-study question? If so, please mark as such.

Comment: Do you mean that under H_0 $\psi$ is a vector or matrix of constants?

Comment: @AdamO No, it is a matrix/vector of unknowns.

Comment: @Narjems then what is the alternative hypothesis? How do you calculate the two likelihoods?

Comment: @AdamO that's what I am wondering about. The alternative is maybe α different from Aψ? It is the Gonzalo Granger likelihood test.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a trivial R question.

If you input a formula to LR test, it just fits the formula with `lm` and then calculates as a null model the intercept-only counterpart.

It doesn't test anything like the null hypothesis that you've written, where the linear combination of coefficients is equal to some constant. You'll need a very complex fitting strategy to do that. Or maybe the terminology is just not being used clearly.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, but do you know what can I do instead?